# Result limiting with GAE Search API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, search, full-text-search, gae-search

I have this search code that is quite bugging me,

```
if(webSafeCursor != null && !webSafeCursor.isEmpty()){
    Cursor cursor = Cursor.newBuilder().build(webSafeCursor);
    QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder()
                           .setLimit(10)
                           .setFieldsToSnippet("content")
                           .setCursor(cursor)
                           .build();
    query = Query.newBuilder()
            .setOptions(options)
            .build(queryString);
    }

    Results<ScoredDocument> results = null;

    if(query != null){
        results = index.search(query);
    } else {
               results = index.search(queryString);
           }
    results.getCursor(); // NULL!
}
```

The problem here is that the `results` returned is 20 items while it is clear in the `QueryOptions` that the limit is 10.

What could be wrong in this code?

And another thing is the query result do not emit a Cursor, whereas it is clear (by manually checking) that the query should return more than 20 items, and that should return a Cursor? Or is this the correct behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as far as I can tell from your code, your queryOptions are only used if you pass in a non-empty cursor. So, if you didn't already have a cursor you won't be getting one either. Add a closing brace after

```
Cursor cursor = Cursor.newBuilder().build(webSafeCursor);
```

and I think you'll get the behavior you want (after balancing the braces elsewhere, of course).